# How do I use a Key thats not found, but is enumarated? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

In my example I am using the camera2 api. I can use CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_LOCK_AVAILABLE, but how about CameraCharacteristics.MEDIATEK_FACE_FEATURE_AVAILABLE_GESTURE_MODES? Obviously Android studio will say cannot find symbol variable.

But this key is enumerated as com.mediatek.facefeature.availablegesturemodes by the code below. How do I use enumerated keys that are not part of the standard list in Android Studio etc?

```
for (CameraCharacteristics.Key <?> key : characteristics.getKeys()) {
                   for (CaptureRequest.Key<?> key : myrequest.getKeys()) {

                        mystring.append(key.getName() + "\n");
                         
                       

                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for that particular Key, you already have one from your call to getKeys and iterating, so you can just look for one with the name you want and then use it with `CameraCharacteristics.get(Key)` or `CaptureRequest.Builder.set(Key, value)`.

You can also directly construct the Key object - the [constructors](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.Key#Key(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) are public as of API 29.  You need the Key name, like `com.mediatek.facefeature.availablegesturemodes`, and you need to know the type of the key as well.  So iterating and matching on name to find the Key is probably simpler, and works on earlier APIs too.

Of course, these custom keys only work on some devices, so you'll have to make your code robust to them missing.  There are no guarantees, unless a particular OEM has said that key is going to be reliable.

Comment: Yeah, I cannot create the key for whatever reason normally outside of a for each loop like that.